# Playing sound from url - Node.JS (Google-TTS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, node-modules, text-to-speech

I am trying to use the google text to speech API in Node.JS. I am generating api links using google-tts-api and want to play them now. Is there any node library, that is able to play sound from a weblink?

```
var tts = require("google-tts-api");
tts(text, "de-DE", 1).then(function(url) {
  playSound(url);
});
function playSound(url) {
  //Some code, that is able to play the audio from the url.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the URL you can try calling `ffplay` as a child process.
But if you just are looking for having node talk to you try [say.js](https://github.com/Marak/say.js) or [tts](https://github.com/eheikes/tts). If you get raw audio (by decoding raw PCM Audio) you can use [node-speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker).

Comment: Thank you! Will be experimenting with that.